# getting "NaN" results from for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, nan

First - so sorry for such a long post. I'm trying to be specific! Thanks for reading it :)
I have two vectors as follows:

`popd = vector(mode='numeric', 100)
popr = vector(mode='numeric', 100)`

These represent the initial distribution within 2 populations. 
I want to define these e.g.

```
popd[]=0.01
popr[]=0.01
```

I also define e=0.05, and the populations will then transform according to the following for loop:

```
loop <- for(i in 1:100)
{π <- function(S)
    {x <- sum(popd[1:S])
    return((100-S)*x)}
µ <- function(A)
    {share <- vector(mode='numeric', (101-A))
    share[] = A:100
    return(share%*%popr[A:100])}
for(S in 1:100){vectorπ <- vector(mode='numeric', 100)
    vectorπ[S]=π(S)}
for(A in 1:100){vectorµ <- vector(mode='numeric', 100)
    vectorµ[A]=µ(A)}
av.payoffd <- sum(popd * vectorπ)
av.payoffr <- sum(popr * vectorµ)
newd <- vector(mode='numeric', 100)
    for(S in 1:100){newd[S]=(popd[S]/(av.payoffd))}
newr <- vector(mode='numeric', 100)
    for(A in 1:100){newr[A]=(popr[A]/(av.payoffr))}
newpopd <- vectorπ * newd
    test1[i,2]=(sum(newpopd * (1:100)))
newpopr <- vectorµ * newr
    test1[i,4]=(sum(newpopr * (1:100)))
mutationmatrix <- function(e)
    {mut <- c(e, 1-(2*e), e)
    return(matrix(c(1-e, e, (rep(c(rep098, mut), times=98)), rep098, e, 1-e), nrow=100))}
mutpopd <- function(e)
    {mutationmatrix(e) %*% newpopd}
    test1[i,3]=(sum(mutpopd(e) * (1:100)))
mutpopr <- function(e)
    {mutationmatrix(e) %*% newpopr}
    test1[i,5]=(sum(mutpopr(e) * (1:100)))
if(i<100){
    popd=mutpopd(e)
    popr=mutpopr(e)
}
if(i==100){
    for(i in 1:100){
    popdistcomp1[i,3]=mutpopd(e)[i,1]
    popdistcomp1[i,6]=mutpopr(e)[i,1]}
}
}
```

test1 and popdistcomp1 are both matrices I have already defined.
However, when I ask for the results I get:

```
test1
         i meanoffer meanmutoffer meanminaccept meanmutminaccept
  [1,]   1       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [2,]   2       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [3,]   3       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [4,]   4       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [5,]   5       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [6,]   6       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [7,]   7       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [8,]   8       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
  [9,]   9       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
 [10,]  10       NaN          NaN           100            99.95
```

and

```
popdistcomp1
       p(i)   initialpopd mutatedpopd q(a)   initialpopr mutatedpopr
  [1,] "p1"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q1"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [2,] "p2"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q2"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [3,] "p3"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q3"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [4,] "p4"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q4"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [5,] "p5"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q5"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [6,] "p6"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q6"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [7,] "p7"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q7"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [8,] "p8"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q8"   "0.01"      "0"        
  [9,] "p9"   "0.01"      "NaN"       "q9"   "0.01"      "0"        
 [10,] "p10"  "0.01"      "NaN"       "q10"  "0.01"      "0"
```

I've only showed the first 10 entries for the sake of space but they continue in much the same vein, though I should probably say that the last two entries of popdistcomp1 under mutatedpopr are 0.05 and 0.95.

What I'm unsure of is where the "NaN" entries are coming from. I guess there's an issue in the code somewhere, or maybe it's a problem with the structure of my loop. I am a complete beginner, been using R for about 5 days so apologies if I'm being daft.

Thanks for any help,

Lucy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions to start out:

`R` is highly vectorized, so avoid writing tons of 'microfunctions'.  For one thing, you're lucky that objects like `popd` happen to be visible to the function (since you didn't pass them into the function).  Try `my.pi <- sum(popd[1:S]*(100-S)` instead.

`for` doesn't return a value, so don't type `foo<-for(....` .

Don't use greek symbols. It doesn't help and may well fail to transfer to other systems.

And finally, do some debug work.  Take a look at every calculation which precedes the calculation of `meanoffer`, aka `test1[,4]`, examine the output of every step, and see where `NaN` first appears.  Your steps are pretty straightforward, so the error should pop up pretty easily.

Comment: Hi Carl. Thanks very much for those pointers. I know it has a silly number of functions within the for loop - i'd much rather this wasn't the case as it is awful to type out, but I'm not sure how else to do it, any suggestions? popd and popr have to be defined outwith the loop surely or else it will loop back and take those values again?

Comment: oops. I didn't mean to press enter just yet. I'm in the process of going through the loop and will hopefully find something.

Comment: Yes, define them outside the loop; my point was that functions have their own environment so it's risky to have them use objects which are not explicitly passed in as arguments to the functions.

Comment: I've found the bug! Thanks @Carl. also your profile made me smile as it made me look up those dogs...who couldn't smile upon seeing them! so cheers.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem.  Hope you like `R` ; and BTW programming is always more fun with a puppy snuggled in your chair!